Wait for a response before loading template
I have an angular application that makes a server call on ngOnInit() and returns a result. I then use the result to populate a model in my template. My template is loading before the call is finished, giving me an undefined error. How can I ensure the call has completed before the template loads?
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.GetCurrentSelectedProducts();
}

GetCurrentSelectedProducts() {
    this.proposalService.getCurrentSelectedProducts(this.proposalId).subscribe(response => {
      this.productResponse = response.result;
    });
}

..
<select [(ngModel)]="productResponse.Id">


Here you are: https://angular.dev/api/core/@if#

Not what I'm looking for

Did you try async pipe?

@SrikarPhaniKumarM I did try <select [(ngModel)]="productResponse.Id | async"> to no luck

try <select [(ngModel)]="(productResponse | async) ?.Id">

2 ways to fix it:
// Way 1: Use ngIf / @if
<select *ngIf="productResponse.id" [(ngModel)]="productResponse.Id">

// (or) if you are using latest versions of angular then

@if(productResponse.id) {
  <select [(ngModel)]="productResponse.Id">
}


// Way 2: Declare an observable for productResponse and then use it with
// async pipe. 

// in component.ts

productResponse$: Observable<YOUR_RESPONSE_INTERFACE_OR_MODEL>;

ngOnInit() {
this.productResponse$ =  this.proposalService.getCurrentSelectedProducts(this.proposalId)
}

// in html: 
<ng-container *ngIf="productResponse$ | async as productResponse">
  <select [(ngModel)]="productResponse.Id">
    <!-- your options here -->
  </select>
</ng-container>


This is the expected behavior. As your API call is asynchronous, it will resolve sometime in future, while your template loading is completed.
To fix, you can try these

Put conditional checks in the template *ngIf or @if based on angular version and try to show some loading graphics.
If the data is required to be loaded before template is rendered, then make the api calls in the 'resolve' of the router


How can I use *ngIf on [(ngModel)]?

Here you are: https://v17.angular.io/api/common/NgIf ... if you prefere old stuff

Solution 1. As we know that [(ngModel)]="productResponse.Id" is the short form of
[ngModel]="productResponse.Id"
 (ngModelChange)="productResponse.Id = $event"

You could just simply use conditional operator like this and you wont get error - [ngModel]="productResponse?.Id" (ngModelChange)="productResponse.Id = $event"
Solution 2. Or you could just wrap the whole thing in ng-container and use ngIf like this -
<ng-container *ngIf="productResponse">
  <select [(ngModel)]="productResponse.Id">
    <!-- your options here -->
  </select>
</ng-container>

